# RewriteRule for a file in a parent directory

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I've got a site set up on an apache server with the desktop site in /public_html and a mobile site /in public_html/mob

I'm trying to set up an .htaccess rewriterule to send users to an index.php file in /public_html if they visit the /mob folder. My current rewrite rule, in the mob subfolder is:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ../index.php
```

I can load up the same file in the mob subdirectory with:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ index.php
```

However I can't seem to get the site to load the index.php file from the parent directory (public_html).

When attempting to load http://www.domain.com/mob in a browser I receive:

```
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
```

This same rewriterule worked fine on our development server, but doesn't work in our live environment.

The .htaccess file from the /public_html/mob folder is as follows:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ../index.php [L,QSA]
```

When index.php is reached a mobile device detect script decides whether to load the content from the desktop or mobile site.

Comment: where is this .htaccess file? In the site's document root, or in the mob subfolder?

Comment: The .htaccess file I'm trying to get this rule to work in it in the mob subfolder.

Comment: Does mobile site have a separate subdomain like `m.domain.com`? OR is it only used as `domain.com/mob`? Also can you provide existing .htaccess from `/mob` folder?

Comment: @anubhava Yes this is the second part of the m.domain.com post that you solved for me earlier. Once this is fixed the site should work correctly.

I've added a simplified version of the .htaccess file in the /public_html/mob folder. Which has the same results (Bad request)

Comment: Oh I see but why do you want to redirect all the traffic from mobile site to main site unconditionally?

Comment: @anubhava The index.php in the public_html directory contains a mobile device detect script which determines which content to load (mobile/desktop). The mobile site uses the same codebase as the desktop site.

Comment: alight and you want internal rewrite only? (I mean withut changing URL in the browser)?

Comment: @anubhava So the user would visit http://www.domain.com/contact and if they're using a mobile device the mobile device detect will redirect them to http://m.domain.com/contact. The rewrite rule to go in this htaccess just needs to ensure that the server loads the index.php file in the public_html directory.

Comment: Well if `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for `m.domain.com` is `/public_html/mob` then you cannot load `/public_html/index.php` without doing a full redirect to `http://domain.com/index.php`

Comment: @anubhava Could you explain why? I have a plain html file `/public_html/holding.html` that I can load with the following `RewriteRule ^(/)?$ ../holding.html` but I can't use the same rule for index.php. I just tried changing document root for `m.domain.com` to `/public_html` and if I load it now I get redirected to `www.m.domain.com`

Comment: That `www.m.domain.com` is probably happening because of some rule in main `.htaccess`. Any site cannot access files above DOCUMENT_ROOT folder.

Comment: I am not sure how you can load `/public_html/holding.html` from `m.domain.com` if its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is `/public_html/mob`.

Comment: @anubhava You were right, I'd temporarily changed the rule you helped me with earlier. From a .htaccess point of view everything now appears to be working correctly. Thank you so much!

Comment: @anubhava Would you like to answer the question, mention that I needed to check my `DOCUMENT_ROOT` and I'll accept your answer.

Comment: Alright provided an answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

- Check `DOCUMENT_ROOT` of your `m.domain.com`.

If `DOCUMENT_ROOT` for your `m.domain.com` is `/public_html/mob` then you cannot load `/public_html/index.php` without doing a full redirect (or proxy) to `http://domain.com/index.php`

- Just to clarify any web site cannot access files above its `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder level.

Answer (score 1):

If your rule's target starts with a `/`, that makes it an absolute URI starting from the *document root*, which I assume would be the public_html folder:

```
RewriteRule ^(/)?$ /index.php
```

Comment: Definitely needs to go up a directory. Only using / and not ../ results in 404 not found.